# Get the id of the current div when key press 

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 `div` parts in my `HTML` document, and i am trying to toggle between each other whenever the key press. The idea is, when a key press event is occured, i got the `id` of the current `div` and depending on that `id`, i fade in the right `div`(if it's div 1, fade in div 2, etc.).

My HTML code is the following:

```
<div id="home" class="current">
        <p align="center">Home</p>
        <p align="center">
           Some content
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
        <p align="center">About</p>
        <p align="center">
           Some content 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
        <p align="center">Contact Form</p>
        <p align="center">
            Some content
        </p>
    </div>
```

The `jQuery` code:

```
<script>
$("#target").keypress(function(){

        var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
          console.log('id is: '+id);    
        $('.current').fadeOut(900, function(){
            $('#'+id).fadeIn(900);
            $('.current').removeClass('current');
            $('#'+id).addClass('current');

        });

    });
</script>
​
```

The code above doesn't work, i am new with `jQuery` events, could you please guiding me to the right way.

Comment: Isn't `keypress` API which handle the any key press?

Comment: I can't find the "any" key on my keyboard.

Comment: In JavaScript, `onKeyDown` handle the ALL keys press event. That's what i mean. I tried to make the same in `jQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keyup` and `.val` instead.

```
$("#target").keyup(function(){

    var id = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.current').removeClass('current').fadeOut(900, function(){
        $('#'+id).fadeIn(900).addClass('current');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I implemented your code, when i key press, nothing happen although no error is detected in the console.

Comment: Because the user isn't "keypressing" on #target. i think you've to add a listener to the whole document, and retrieve the id from $('.current')

Answer (score 1):

You need an event listener. You can remove the keyCode conditional statement if you want it to be any key (instead of a specific one)

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {             // enter key
  var id = $('.current').attr('id');
  if (id == "whatever") {
    ............
  } else if (id == "somethingelse") {
    ............
  }
 }
});
```